# Can't access containers in vscode showing message "shell server terminated code 255" after doing nothing

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers, ssh-keygen, remote-development

I normaly access remote containers of host via remote explorer in vscode installed in my local computer.
After I generated ssh-key "other host" that I've used, VScode started to show error message below.. and now I can't open folders both of "this host" and "other host".

[Errormesage when connect open folder in container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67xqO.png)

Shell server terminated (code: 255, signal: null) XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�. node:child_process:925 throw err; ^ Error: Command failed: wmic process where (commandline like "%ssh-askpass.bat%") get processid,parentprocessid /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv" XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�. at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:848:11) at Object.execSync (node:child_process:922:15) at Object. (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:12704) at Object. (c:\Users\USER.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\common\sshAskpass.js:5:808) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:876:12) at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343) at Function.executeUserE...

I've (1) removed ssh-key from host and (2) re-installed vscode from my local computer, but that is not the solution. Thankfully, docker attach command is still working, but which means I have to use vi editor like SW development several decades ago!
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you- future responder for saving my life

Answer (score 1):

It Worked for me by updating the Dev Container extension from v0.266.1 to v0.268.0, pre-release version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved by replacing en-us with ko-KR in the sshAskpass.js file.

There was no csv file in %WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us and there was a csv file in %WINDIR%\System32\wbem\ko-KR

Comment: Your solution is not work for my case. Anyhow, Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

It Worked for me by copying the content of fr-FR file of WINDIR C:\Windows\System32\wbem\ in the en-US file